# Rebase a remote feature branch without any changes in the feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, push, rebase

We have two branches on the remote repo master and release. After creating release branch in the remote repo, there were some changes in the master branch related to same release and now I need to get those changes to remote release branch as well. Lets assume this is how it looks when I created the release branch

`A-B  (master)
    \
     B  (releasevX.Y)`

Now there were few commits on the master as below

`A-B-C-D-E-F-G  (master)
    \
     B  (releasevX.Y)`

Now commits C and D is related to release vX.Y and I would like to rebase my remote releasevX.Y branch to commit D as below

`A-B-C-D-E-F-G  (master)
        \
         D  (releasevX.Y)`

I understand the easiest way to do this is to delete the remote releasevX.Y branch and create a new one. But I do not have permission to create remote branches. 
I tried using *'git reset --hard'* and *'git rebase'* along with *'git push --force'* but i get following error

> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/releasevX.Y (no new changes)
>   error: failed to push some refs to

I understand that it is rejecting since there is no local changes on the branch. But how can I align my remote releasevX.Y branch to different commit of the master branch without re-creating the branch?

All the changes are pushed through gerrit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Gerrit. The push fails because `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` have been pushed to `refs/for/master` before. A commit can't be reviewed and submitted twice.

If `releasevX.Y` does not exist in the remote repository yet, you could ask someone to create the ref on `D` on the web UI. This someone should have the access right `Create Reference` on `refs/heads/*`. If you have the right, you can do it yourself.

If it exists, you could ask someone to push `D` to `releasevX.Y` with `git push origin D:releasevX.Y`, if this someone has the access right `Push` on `refs/heads/*`.

The last option is that you run `git checkout releasevX.Y;git merge D --no-ff;git push origin HEAD:refs/for/releasevX.Y`. You already have the access right `Push` on `refs/for/*`. This solution creates a merge commit although it could have been a fast-forward merge.

So if you'd like the history to be neat and clean, either get more access rights or ask someone who has the rights to do it.

Comment: I would really like not to have a dummy or merge commit as I want my release branch to be mirror of a particular commit on master but I think I need to live with this as I do not find any other option (not a fan of other two options you mentioned)!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to rebase the `releasevX.Y` branch on commit `D`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -B releasevX.Y <commit id for D>
git cherry-pick <commit id for D>
git push -f
```

Then the commit history will look:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G  master
       \
        D'    releasevX.Y
```

**Note:**

- `-B` option for `git checkout` command will reset `releasevX.Y` based on the new specified commit `D` since the `releasevX.Y` branch name already exist.

Comment: Even this method is fine until i do 'git push'. I tried to do a 'git push --force' by adding a dummy commit and I was able to push to gerrit. So I do have the permission. Only problem is I can push just the master branch rebased commits without any local changes.

Comment: Where does your remote repo hosted? For GitHub there seems no such setting.

Comment: Its not in Github.

Comment: So it mainly the branch policies for the remote repo. You did should add a dummy commit on `releasevX.Y` branch. And I updated my answer :)